# Personal statements in my motivation letter?

Tags: application-cover-letter, motivation

I am applying for the CERN summer program. On their YT channel they empathise to write a lot about us as persons, so passions, hobby’s, etc.
In your opinion should I write some personal statements in my motivation letter, like:

1. My strong passion and independent study for history/ philosophy
2. I enjoy sincere art and drawing since I was a child.
3. The fact that I was born and raised in a country, then with my family I moved to another country and this experience made me understood life’s most important lessons. This is a key point because I really think that CERN is an amazing community that shares all my values, integrity, importance of diversity, adaptability. So this statements are not just words but some important reasons for which I apply, but they concern my personal life. Clearly in addition to that I have a deep passion for physics, but also my history explains why I would be honoured to spend my summer at CERN instead of any other place.

Clearly in the letter I write all in a more formal way.

Comment: Next time if you  want to post something here, please put some effort into your post

Answer (score 1):

Think about the tone of what you write. I don't have an easy way to see their explicit instructions, but if they mention "passion" and "hobbies" and such then what you write here doesn't seem sincere, especially the first to samples. It reads like you are checking off boxes to fulfill requirements. That is a bit stilted.

If they specifically ask for "passion" and you answer "... passion..." it will seem that way. Think deeper about what you really want to get from time at CERN and how it fits into the larger picture of your goals.

Your third point is getting much closer to the way you want to write, I suggest.